# Next.js 404 error after refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I try to learn Next.js but I have a small problem.
Here is my test code:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
export default () => (
    <p>Hallo next <Link href="/abouts?id=2" as='/abouts/1'><a>About</a></Link></p>
)
```

If I clicked in link About from index.js page, my url look `'/about/1/'` and work fine, but if I refresh page I get error 404. If I type in browser `/abouts?id=2"` and refresh page everything works fine. Do u know how I can fix this ?
I want have links like

```
/about/1/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Next.js documentation](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#with-link):

> The second `as` parameter for `push` and `replace` is an optional *decoration* of the URL. Useful if you configured custom routes on the server.

So to achieve this behavior, you'll need to configure custom routes inside your `server.js`—for example using `express`. Extend your server with this:

```js
const next = require('next');
const express = require('express');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  // Nice permalinks for pages.
  // Sets up a custom route, that then uses next.js to render the about page.
  server.get('/about/:id', (req, res) => {
    const params = { id: req.params.id };
    return app.render(req, res, '/about', params);
  });

  // For all other routes, use next.js.
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`${'\u2705'}  Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un archivo .htaccess, por ejemplo para un dominio xyz.com donde se creo un portal con nextjs puedes usar este archivo:

```
  RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```